# Arkit - Rotate object with camera rotation

Tags: rotation, scenekit, arkit

How can I rotate a sphere accordingly to the camera rotation?
Example: if i walk around my sphere, the sphere rotates with me, that I always see the same side.

Answer (score 1):

Use a constraint, for example a [`SCNLookAtConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) to your view's [`pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview).

Comment: Is it possible that only the pivot rotates with the camera and the sphere doesn't. My goal is that I can walk around the sphere and the pan gesture up/down is always along the camera-sphere vector direction?

Comment: No. You should probably ask a question with all your desired outcome, your current code and what exactly is the problem you are needing help with.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I need to merge everything and than ask a new question with everything (sketch, code, etc.) in it. I'll put a link to the new complete question in the comments.